# PHP MySQL Delete parent and child rows

Tags: mysql, parent, children, sql-delete

I have 1 MySQL Table. It looks like this:

```
+---------+-------------+--------+
| item_id |  parent_id  |  Name  |
+---------+-------------+--------+
|   1     |     0       |  Home  |
+---------+-------------+--------+
|   2     |     1       |  Sub   |
+---------+-------------+--------+
|   3     |     2       | SubSub |
+---------+-------------+--------+
```

If I DELETE item_id 1, I want to delete the rest of the sub also but how can I do it?

I have tried the Foreign Key but it works only if you have 2 tables??

I hope someone can help me in MySQL maybe PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, most definitely, use self-referencing foreign keys with MySQL (you don't need multiple tables). However, for any kind of foreign key support, you need to use the [`InnoDB` engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-storage-engine.html). And my guess is, that you are using the [`MyISAM` engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html).

With `InnoDB` you could create a table, similar to what you have already, including the self-referencing foreign key, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE  `yourTable` (
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`item_id`),
  KEY `FK_parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `yourTable` (`item_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then, when you issue a `DELETE` statement, like:

```
DELETE FROM `yourTable` WHERE `item_id` = 1;
```

... it would delete each 'child' row, that has a `parent_id` of `1` as well. If any of those 'child' rows have children of their own, they'd be deleted too, etc. (that's what the `ON DELETE CASCADE` means).

Comment: You can do this with a self join on the table and not creating another table.

Comment: When I want to insert my data I get this error: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: @user2180410 When using foreign key constraints: if you insert a row with a non-null `parent_id` value, a record that has `item_id` with that same value, must exist beforehand, unless you disable foreign keys, temporarily (which I would advice against, as this defeats their purpose). Foreign key constaints are used to ensure data-integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Easier actually than thought:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = # OR parent_id = #; //where # is the same in both places.
```

Example:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 1 OR parent_id = 1;
```

Comment: The thing is though, that this will not `cascade` further down. As you can see from OP's example table, the record with `item_id = 2` also has a child row of its own (`item_id = 3`), that will not be deleted with your solution. If OP is OK with this, this will suffice, but OP should be aware that your solution would create orphan records.

Comment: Why did I get a down vote for a good answer with a limited scope?? I thought he meant if the id is 1, delete children with parent of 1. I did not understand he wanted all the way down.

Comment: In addition a join could solve this. Making a second table is exceptionally inefficient and not a good solve of the problem.

Comment: No one is suggesting OP should create a second table. My suggestion was to replace the existing table with a table using the `InnoDB` engine, so that OP could utilize foreign keys. And `JOIN`ing, as you suggest, won't help either, because it will not cascade further than the amount of `JOIN`s you create.