# T-SQL How to delete all child items while deleting parent

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

so I'm kind of in a tough situation right now (for me atleast). I'm a new programmer, I'm working as a Junior programmer at a company. I have a task where I have to do the following:

When you delete the parent item, the all child tasks associated must be deleted. For example: In this table above, if a user deletes 'Parent 1' all the children/grandchild/great grand children and everyone else associated with that child should be deleted.

[image]

So in this case if a user deletes 'Parent 1'. 
- Parent 1 should be deleted along with Child 1, Child 2, Child 3, GrandChild 1, GrandChild 2, GrandChild 3, GrandChild 4.

If a user deletes Child 2, 
- Grandchild 5 should automatically be deleted.

I'm not sure how to write an SQL script that would do this?

Any suggestions please? I am running this query on MS SQL Server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL Delete parent and child rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747353/php-mysql-delete-parent-and-child-rows)

Comment: For Oracle see [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php) page.

Comment: Just ask a colleague for help and some tutoring.

Comment: I'm confused - your title says T-SQL- which is usually MSSQL, your tags say Oracle - or is it just me?

Comment: If this is always the business rule, there should probably be "on delete cascade" foreign keys defined. Then you'd just delete the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a [hierarchical query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) that retrieves all child rows for a given "Parent 1" - **this is version for Oracle database:**.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
START WITH name = 'Parent 1'
CONNECT WITH PRIOR item_no = parent_item_no
```

and now the task becomes simple:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE ItemNo IN (
    SELECT ItemNo 
    FROM table
    START WITH name = 'Parent 1'
    CONNECT WITH PRIOR item_no = parent_item_no
)
```

---

**A version for SQL-Server:**

This is a reqursive query that gives all descendants of `Parent 1` -> [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01ae9/3)

```
WITH q AS(
  SELECT item_no, parent_item_no, name
  FROM t
  WHERE name = 'Parent 1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.item_no, t.parent_item_no, t.name
  FROM t
  JOIN q
  ON t.parent_item_no = q.item_no
)
SELECT * FROM q;
```

And this DELETE statement uses the above query to delete the whole subtree beneath `Parent 1`

```
WITH q AS(
  SELECT item_no, parent_item_no, name
  FROM t
  WHERE name = 'Parent 1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.item_no, t.parent_item_no, t.name
  FROM t
  JOIN q
  ON t.parent_item_no = q.item_no
)
DELETE FROM t WHERE item_no IN (
       SELECT item_no FROM q
);
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a171/1

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and see if it works!. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Msg 336, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near 'name'. If this is intended to be a common table expression, you need to explicitly terminate the previous statement with a semi-colon.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Well, this is a query for [Oracle database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html), since you tagged your question with `Oracle`. But your question's title says `T-SQL` which is MS-SQL. (or SQL-Server). I guess you are trying to run this on SQL-Server. This query doesn't run on SQL-Server.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i should have been more specific. This query was for MS SQL Server

Comment: For future reference, using the correct tags is extremely helpful to you, because it means people who understand SQL Server will read them. It also prevents other people wasting their time answering the wrong question.

Comment: Yea its my first time using stackoverflow. I just added multiple tags and than realized i can only have 3 and deleted the last few ones.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I've appended a version of the query for SQL-Server, tested on SQL-Fidlle which uses SQL-Server version 2012 .

Comment: The above query worked perfectly! Thanks a lot for the help. I really appreciate you going out of your way writing this query and linking the demo and everything (demo really helped)! I tested this and didn't find any issues with it.