# How to rewrite postgresSql query as Spring-data jpa query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am stuck at the moment while trying to write the next query as a spring-data JPA query:

```
with recursive s as (
select *
from t
where file_id = '12345'
union all
select dfs.*
from t dfs
join s on s.file_id = dfs.parent_folder_id
)
select * from s;
```

I have tried the next:

```
@Query(value = "with recursive subfiles as (
select * from t where file_id=?1 
union all 
dfs.* from t dfs join subfiles s 
on s.file_id = dfs.parent_folder_id) 
select file_id from subfiles", nativeQuery = true)
```

But I get the next error:

```
Method threw 'org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException' exception.
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "dfs"
```

The query should list all direct or indirect dependent children for a specific id. (a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020474/t-sql-how-to-delete-all-child-items-while-deleting-parent))

Comment: Does the query as it is in the `@Query` annotation run when you execute it directly in   a postgresql client? On what kind of method is the annotation? Does it have additional parameters like a `Pageable`?

Comment: Yes, it was running properly, but I managed to fix it.

Comment: It was coming up with an error because I was using a static final variable for *t* table. Unfortunately, the value field accepts only compile-time constants.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it using the next format:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
value = "with recursive subfiles as " +
  "(select * " +
  "from t " +
  "where file_id=?1 " +
  "union all " +
  "select dfs.* " +
  "from t dfs " +
  "join subfiles s " +
  "on s.file_id = dfs.parent_folder_id) " +
"select file_id from subfiles")
List<String> listAllByParentId(String folderId);
```